# Why does invokeAll fail with ExecutorService with limited pool size

Tags: java, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I have a class that uses an *ExecutorService* to make url requests, so that they can be run in parallel, and I limit it to a max pool size of 20

```
private static ExecutorService getCachedPool(ThreadFactory threadFactory)
{
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(20, 20,
            60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(),
            threadFactory);
}
```

However I use it as follows:

```
List<Future<ArtistCoverImage>> results = ArtistArtworkOnlineLookup.getExecutorService()
    .invokeAll(lookups);
```

But if I make call and lookups is larger than available pool size it fails. But I dont understand this as the pool size only specifies max threads that can be used, it uses a *SynchronousQueue* rather than a *BlockingQueue* so why arem't the extra lookups just added to the queue.

If I simply change to max pool size Integer.MAX_VALUE

```
private static ExecutorService getCachedPool(ThreadFactory threadFactory)
    {
        return new ThreadPoolExecutor(20, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(),
                threadFactory);
    }
```

there is no problem, but then Im creating rather more pools than I would like. This is a potential problem because Im trying to improve performance on a low powered black box machine and I am trying to minimize extra work.

Comment: What do you mean with "it fails"?

Comment: `SynchronousQueue` does not seem to be useful here at all. You can only add to the "queue" after someone starts pulling from it. Why don't you use the "normal" `LinkedBlockingQueue`?

Comment: Yes I have misunderstood SynchronousQueue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a misconception on your end regarding the capability/behavior of the queue class you picked. That queue isn't unbound or not blocking, to the contrary.

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) tells us:

> New tasks submitted in method execute(java.lang.Runnable) will be rejected when the Executor has been shut down, and also when the Executor uses finite bounds for both **maximum threads** and work queue capacity, and is saturated.

But more importantly, the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) for SynchronousQueue says:

> A blocking queue in which each insert operation must wait for a corresponding remove operation by another thread, and vice versa.

When you feed 20 long running tasks into it, each one goes to a thread. When they are all still running when #21 comes in, the pool is fully used, and the queue immediately says: "I am full, too". Everything is saturated, the new job isn't accepted any more.

Solution: pick a different kind of queue.

Comment: Ive misunderstood what SynchronousQueue is (copy and paste from Executors Class), if I change queue to new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>() then it works okay with max pool size set to 20, thanks.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Glad I could help quickly ;-)